# I spilled water and was successful in messing with the wireless network hardware. Solved the black screen issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, bluetooth, wifi-configuration

I am facing some Wireless Networking issues here. Experts, take a peep.
Laptop Model : Dell Inspiron 11 
I spilled water on my laptop screen accidentally (tada!) (not on the side where WLAN hardware is placed, but on the opposite side near power button). I opened every thing up and let it dry for the whole day and then the screen started working. But there's no wireless activity on my laptop. I am not sure about the way I plugged the white and black wires in my **wireless card - AC 3160**.

- It has two pins labelled - 1 & 2. Where am I supposed to connect the white and black wires?

I used Device Manager to test whether the Network adapters were okay, and its said all are great! I even used Dell System Auto Detect, that detected every driver and hardware but it showed no problem. I also performed a system reset with the latest recovery available.

- Instead of showing a wifi logo, it shows a pc logo with a red cross in my task bar. Where's the problem, I don't get it. Can someone explain?

Comment: If pins 1 & 2 look like https://goo.gl/images/t6ekyU it antennas connectors. Most probably it two MIMO chains, in this case it order not too important.

Comment: So please add OS tag. I suppose it Windows, but which.

Answer (score 0):

For the wireless card - AC 3160, (1) is black and (2) is white (https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Dell+Inspiron+11-3147+Wireless+Card+Replacement/61262).  Although that shouldn't be your problem.  If your wifi stopped working after you spilled water - You probably damaged a section of the board that deals with the wifi circuit.  I hope that the antenna cable management fixes your problem.